# How to run chrome to automatically connect to a remote debugging process?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, remote-debugging, chrome-remote-debugging

I'm having issues finding answer to this question.
Or is it even possible?

Now I'm forced to open `chrome://inspect/#devices`
and manually enter the host:port information.

I would love for a script to handle this, as I'm using multiple instances at the same time, and they are sharing pool of ports. So would love to automate this.